# Autocomplete in Map using knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

Could anyone help check out my code, I am trying to set up the autocomplete while entering an input but does not seem to work: the console shows no error but the autocomplete just wouldn’t work.

Here's the code:

```
var mapApplication = function (){

    var mapsModel = {
        fromAddress: ko.observable(),
        toAddress: ko.observable()
    };
    // method to add custom binding handler to the KO
    var configureBindingHandlers = function(){
        // custom binding for address auto complete
        ko.bindingHandlers.addressAutoComplete = {
            init: function(element, valueAccessor){
            //create autocomplete object
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element, {types:['geocode']});
            // when user selects an address from the drop down, populate the address in the model.
            var value = valueAccessor();
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function(){
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                console.log(place);
                value(place);
            });
            }
        };
    };

    var init = function(){
        // add code to initialise the module
        ko.applyBindings(mapApplication);   
    };

    // execute the init function when the DOM is ready
    $(init);

    return {
        // add member that will be exposed publicly
        mapsModel: mapsModel
    };
}();
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="panel-heading">Address</div>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div id="addressFromFields" class="form-group">
    <label for="autocompleteFromAddress"> From Address</label>
    <input id="autocompleteFromAddress" class="form-control" data-bind="addressAutoComplete: mapApplication.mapsModel.fromAddress" placeholder="where are u from" type="text">
  </div>

  <div id="addressToFields" class="form-group">
    <label for="autocompleteToAddress"> From Address</label>
    <input id="autocompleteToAddress" class="form-control" data-bind="addressAutoComplete: mapApplication.mapsModel.toAddress" placeholder="where are you going" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "doesn't work"? Is your callback for the autocomplete listener called?

Answer (score 0):

When you `ko.applyBindings(mapApplication)`, the name `mapApplication` is not retained inside Knockout. Its contents become the `$data` object, the top-level context, which you don't normally use by name, it's implied. So your bindings should be, e.g.,

```
data-bind="addressAutoComplete: mapsModel.toAddress"
```

Comment: Hey, thank for taking time to reply but I tried the idea u suggested but it dint work....what do you think?

Comment: I don't know. The construction is a bit confusing to my eyes, and there's no fiddle to play with. You just need to trace through it and see if things are what you expect them to be at various points.

Comment: Do you ever call `configureBindingHandlers`? It doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet with your code in it. I pulled the bindinghandler definition out, because it was not getting created and it isn't really part of your viewmodel code, it's an extension of Knockout.

The error I get at this point is that there is no such thing as `google.maps.places`

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.addressAutoComplete = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    console.debug('GMP', google.maps);
    //create autocomplete object
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element, {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
    console.debug("Autocomplete:", autocomplete);
    // when user selects an address from the drop down, populate the address in the model.
    var value = valueAccessor();
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      console.log(place);
      value(place);
    });
  }
};

var mapApplication = function() {

  var mapsModel = {
    fromAddress: ko.observable(),
    toAddress: ko.observable()
  };

  var init = function() {
    // add code to initialise the module
    ko.applyBindings(mapApplication);
  };

  // execute the init function when the DOM is ready
  $(init);

  return {
    // add member that will be exposed publicly
    mapsModel: mapsModel
  };
}();

console.debug("What is going on?");
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>

<div class="panel-heading">Address</div>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div id="addressFromFields" class="form-group">
    <label for="autocompleteFromAddress">From Address</label>
    <input id="autocompleteFromAddress" class="form-control" data-bind="addressAutoComplete: mapApplication.mapsModel.fromAddress" placeholder="where are u from" type="text">
  </div>

  <div id="addressToFields" class="form-group">
    <label for="autocompleteToAddress">From Address</label>
    <input id="autocompleteToAddress" class="form-control" data-bind="addressAutoComplete: mapApplication.mapsModel.toAddress" placeholder="where are you going" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```